# Rails jQuery pageless problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's the deal,

I'm trying to solve why pageless (infinite scroll) isn't rendering.  Using [this jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless)

I have my index page of products with pagination by will_paginate:

```
def index
  @products = Product.find(:all, :order => "position DESC").paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])

  if request.xhr?
    render :partial => 'shared/products', :object => @products
  end
end
```

My index page is calling the products partial

```
<%= render "shared/products", :object => @products %>
```

Which in turn is passing the collection onto a singular product partial

```
<%= render 'shared/product', :collection => @products %>
```

And calling pageless on it if javascript is enabled (otherwise will_paginate steps in.

```
<%= pageless(@products.total_pages, products_path) %>

-----------

def pageless(total_pages, url=nil, container=nil)
  opts = {
    :totalPages => total_pages,
    :url        => url,
    :loaderMsg  => 'Loading more results'
  }
  container && opts[:container] ||= container

  javascript_tag("$('#results').pageless(#{opts.to_json});")
end
```

And finally here is the code for the singular product partial

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <li id="product_<%= product.id %>">
    <%= link_to product_image(product), product %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Now when I load the page, there are no js errors, I can see the pages getting loaded in my server logs and yet nothing is rendering.  Everything seems to work perfectly and yet it doesn't render.  Any help would be appreciated.

-Scott

Comment: You haven't given enough information for anyone to solve this without downloading the plugin and running it themselves. The pages are getting loaded on your server, but are they returning the right response? In Chrome, use the Network tab in Developer Tools. In Firefox, use Firebug. Now that you've verified that, is the response getting parsed correctly? Check that $.ajax is using the correct dataType parameter, etc., etc. Where does it go wrong? That's what you need to tell us.

Comment: Thanks.  Got some help and was immediately directed to what you suggested.  Was a problem in the DOM id's and classes.  Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The products weren't being appended to the html.  Turned out to be a class/id issue in the html.  For anyone trying to debug something similar, see Jonathan Tran's comment on the question.

Comment: for those that are having the same issue, what ended up working for me was going into the pageless javascript file and changing the ajax datatype at the very end from 'html' to 'script'

Answer (score 0):

i changed few things to make it work for rails3:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%=  render :partial => 'blah/fooPartial' , :locals => { :foo => @foo}  %>
<%= will_paginate(@foo) %>
<%= pageless(@foo.total_pages, @path ) %>
```

**My FooController:**

```
def index
    @foo = Foo.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).
    order("created_at DESC")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html # index.html.erb
    end
  end
```

**My index.js.erb**

```
$('.row').last().after("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => 'blah/fooPartial' , :locals => { :foo => @foo}).html_safe %>");
```

Also Changed the ajax datatype at the very end from 'html' to 'script' in jquery.pageless.js as suggested by ahuang

Hope this helps!!!cheers!!!